# Parse Server logs in user after signup automatically

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am developing my own parser server and connecting my mobile application to it. I use email verification that is built in parse server and also i use "preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail" to make sure that users verify their emails before login. Both email verification and this prevention works fine.

The only issue is that, although "preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail" is set to true, the user is logged in automatically after signup, which makes it impossible to control user from interacting without verification.

I thought about signing out the user automatically, i can do it on client side but it is unreliable, you know. So, either i should signout the user right after signup at the server side, or i should prevent automatic login after signup. Can you think any way of handling any way to handle this safely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Automatic login after signup when `preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail` is `true` looks like a bug. I think you should create an issue in [their github repo](https://github.com/parse-community) and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been resolved in version 2.6.1, released today. Upon a signup call, with your current setup, no session will be created and only the recently created user will be returned. If you feel we should not return the existing user, please let us know in an issue!